# Rare creature spawns

Tags: borderlands-2

Borderlands 2 has various rare monster spawns. Named creatures that only sometimes show up. Does anybody have a list of where which guys spawn?

How many are there?

These rare creatures also have certain types of weapons they are more likely to spawn. Does anybody know which creature is more likely to which items?

Comment: This may be a list that's too large for what is generally acceptable for Arqade; we try to limit it to ~50 or so.  Any idea how many rare monsters there are?

Comment: Not at all. I could not find a list on any wiki. So I used Arqade.

Comment: Bosses always (best I can tell) spawn, only rare creatures I know of are the loot goons and Jimmy Jenkins (who is effectively a loot midget)...are there others?

Comment: Yeah, King Mong, Donkey Mong, Savage Lee, etc. And there are more. I saw a developer youtube movie where he encountered another named enemy. (Don't know what it was, some robot). So there are more. And I think they are tied to a location.

Comment: JEEEEENNNNNNNNNNNKIIIIIIIIIIINNNNNNNNNNNNSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!

Comment: I saw a poster for Jenkins !! It said he was missing...I have yet to find him

Comment: This page borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Weapon_Effects_Borderlands_2 contains some info I'm after btw. But not all.

Comment: http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=150790 more info! :D

Comment: Sadly the link above is now dead. Don't think this question is really answerable that easily.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the place where the boss bloodwing was in the mission wildlife exploitation reserve and it will spawn The Mother Rakk, it's a giant rakk. it's not very hard to kill. Can drop rare loot, but no idea if it drops any legendary though. There is Savage Lee which you can find in three horns Divide living among bullymongs and he has a chance to drop that Unkempt Harold, which is by many players considered to be the best pistol in the game. There is Scorch in Frostburn Canyon, could drop Hellfire legendary SMG. There are loot midjets that can be found in many maps through the game, but if you don't finish the mission Doctor's Orders there will always be 2 loot midjets and 2 loot midjet robots in the 4 small boxes in wildlife exploitation where they run experiments on skags. They can drop many legendaries. These aren't really rare but they are hard to find. Except for Scorch a side quest leads you to him. Good luck :)

Answer (score -2):

The only one I know is [Terramorphous the Invincible](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Terramorphous_the_Invincible). You need eridium to spawn him, and it usually takes 4 players around level 50 to take him down.

Comment: Please try to use proper punctuation.

Comment: That is not the only one, and he is related to a quest. So he is not rare, nor hard to find. I meant stuff like 'king mong, donkey mong, savage lee, jimmy jenkins etc' Look for them in the comments on the question.